# SSIS Package upgrade from 2008 to 2016

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2015. I would like to upgrade my SSIS packages from 2008 version to 2016. From online search, I got to know that if I just add existing  2008 package into VS 2015 and right click on SSIS package and click on Upgrade all  packages. It will update all the packages. But, I am not able to select any existing packages in a "SSIS package upgrade wizard" Can anyone please help?

I would like Visual studio to detect my 2008 package. Please refer the screenshot below.

[image]

Comment: How did you get to this screen?   List all the steps you took to reproduce this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You may try opening the solution created in 2008 in 2015 and then try upgrading a particular package by rt clicking it.